# Username displays incorrectly in GUIs, correct in terminal

Tags: login-screen

My username, which was set for me by university IT, is spelled correctly in the system, shows up correctly in terminal, in my home folder, etc. However, in all the GUI menus and login screen, it appears to be spelled with an "l" instead of a "y". The letter "y" renders correctly elsewhere.

Any reason this might occur? Any ideas on how to fix it? Not a serious problem, just irksome to look at.

Comment: Try chenging the Keyboard-Language from the Language you have to an another and change it back then reboot the System.
I dont know if this will work but try it

Comment: Are you using English language? Could you provide screenshot of this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to see if the real name is written in the wrong way:

```
grep rmano /etc/passwd
```

gives

```
rmano:x:1001:1001:Romano Gtti,,,:/home/rmano:/bin/zsh \
```

the first is the username, the name after the second number ("Romano Gtti") is the one that appears in login screen etc.

If it's incorrect, you can change it with `sudo chfn -f "New Name" user` (thanks @steeldriver) or (dangerously) by editing `/etc/passwd` with `sudo vipw`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I was able to fix it by editing that line in /etc/passwd.

Comment: A possibly safer way is to use the `chfn` (change fullname) utility e.g. `sudo chfn -f "New Name" user`

Answer (score 3):

You have two user names - the lowercase name that is used in terminal and to name your home folder directory *(e.g. mine's `wilf`)*, and the display name, which can have UPPERCASE letters, your surname etc *(e.g. mine's `Wilfred`)*.

It is likely that you can change this name in settings, if you have the admin password for the machine.
[image: User Settings]